# elasticsearch can't start with an non-root user

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch as a search engine for my website.After I downloaded the elasticsearch I use the command ./bin/elasticsearch 
I got an error

```
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
```

I google it and run the command

```
groupadd esgroup        
useradd esuser -g esgroup -p espassword
chown -R esuser:esgroup elasticsearch
```

and I switch to esuser but I cant cd /root

```
bash: cd: /root: Permission denied
```

so I have to switch to root user and stay at /root/elasticsearch/ and change to esuser 
 then I run the command

```
./bin/elasticsearch
```

this time I get a different error

```
Error: Could not find or load main classorg.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
```

I already install  java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel and the java -version javac command works
I am using centos6 x64
Is there something I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please download & install the whole elasticsearch zip as a non-root user instead of trying to fiddle with permissions inside of the `/root/` directory (where also data & logs are written to).

if you dont want to deal with such things, the easiest way might be to use one of the existing packages.

Comment: Thank you very very much.I stuck here for almost two days.Try every method I searched from Internet but still the same error.Again thank you.